# Did I do Pacifist correct? (I think I am missing something.)

Tags: undertale

I got to Asgore with 0 EXP and then I did the fight. I had the worn knife on me that I found as well as the heart locket. I did the fight and spared Asgore and of course Flowey killed him and then I battled Omega Flowey and I had to attack him as well. I spared him. I did not do the date with Papyrus or Alphys. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restart, really. there are key events (the dates being some) that are required to get Pacifist done correctly.

Comment: I *think* you should be able to access the dates still when you reload the previous save.

Comment: that's provided that they haven't saved after the points where they're possible, though, right? i'd assume there's some form of "point of no return" at some point in playthrough

Comment: I don't believe so, the last save after a first 0 exp playthrough should let you go back for at *least* the alphys date, and you should have access to snowdin etc too

Comment: huh, interesting. i never attempted it, so i figured that they'd have something to stop it,

Comment: The True Pacifist speedrun gets the alphys date after Omega flowey on the same file so I imagine the others are also possible, but I'm not certain

Comment: i'd have to test to be certain, but i don't have the ability to do that at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Reload your last save and go interact with the main characters (Papyrus, Alphys, and  Undyne). There is no point of no return or anything.